# Why is there no future-1 vs future-2 distinction in the future passive?

Tags: passive, future

I know of two passive construction for future:

1. Repeat werden + present tense of verb
2. Present tense passive + indication of time

And I also know two future constructions, future-1, future-2. Why is that in passive, there is no future-1 passive or future-2 passive but a general future passive?

Comment: Your premise is wrong. The passive of the second future requires four verbs to express and is correspondingly cumbersome and rare, but it does exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is, [as explained on this site](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/passiv/passivs-tempus-zeitformen/)

They give two examples:

**Futur 1**

> Aktiv: Der Arzt wird den Mann operieren.
> Passiv: Der Mann wird (von dem Arzt) operiert werden.

**Futur 2**

> Aktiv: Der Arzt wird den Mann operiert haben.
> Passiv: Der Mann wird (von dem Arzt) operiert worden sein.